# Is there a Visual Studio Extension that implements a find or search dialog similar to the one from VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio

Pretty much the question headline.
Is there a Visual Studio Extension that implements a find or search dialog similar to the one from Visual Studio 2010?

**"Find-in-files" is not an acceptable alternative explained below.**

It has been at least 7 years.  There must be one by now.

I have a tendency to highlight a word, method, property, class, or whatever, hit ctrl-f, then switch to another tab to see how it got used in the other file.  The quick find box does not retain the search value between windows.

I also need my search in files dialog to stay at the scope that it is set, because I use it to do what it says on the tin a lot.  So toggling between current document and entire solution is not a viable solution.  It is also too easy to accidentally fill your search results window with the current page scope that you didn't want to do that.

Comment: You can always select "Current document" in the pre-VS2019 Find-in-Files tool window and get the results in the Find Results window which you can keep open. VS2019's new Find-and-Replace tool window also has "Look in: Current document" and the new Find Results window has a button labelled "Keep results" which lets you keep an unlimited number of results open, instead of being limited to just "Find results 1" and "Find results 2".

Comment: That is my problem, I don't want to keep toggling that selection.  I don't want to be able to accidentally populate my search results panel with current document results.

Comment: But if you use the "Keep results" option then it won't be as-big a problem if you accidentally perform a new search because you can quickly go-back to your previous results.

Comment: You are ignoring the part where I constantly have to switch between "Current document only" and "Entire Project/Solution"